# Making a square

Tags: python, syntax-error

so I've just started coding in python and I've been assigned a project to approximate the value of pi using a Monte Carlo algorithm. I've already got the conceptual bit down but now I'm required to print out a square and place check marks on it. the square needs to be defined by a user set size.

I've managed to get the square to print using the following code:

```
import random
#defines the size of the square
squareSize = raw_input("Enter a square size:")
#defines the width of the square
print "#" * (int(squareSize)+2)
#defines the length of the square. 
for i in range(0,int(squareSize)):

    print "#", " " * (int(squareSize)-2), "#"

print "#" * (int(squareSize)+2)
```

For whatever reason when I add:

```
#determines the x value of a point to display
x = random.uniform(-1*(squareSize),squareSize)
```

or anything else that creates a variable that messes with the "squareSize" I receive the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 6, in <module>
  File "/lib/python2.7/random.py", line 357, in uniform
    return a + (b-a) * self.random()
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'
```

I'd appreciate any help I can get with this, I'm sure it's something stupid that I'm just overlooking but I can't for the life of me figure it out.

Thanks,

Alex.

Comment: You forgot the "int" in random.uniform: `random.uniform(-1*int(squaresize),int(squaresize)). But as @alecxe suggest, you should do this operation only once.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `squareSize` is of a `str` type. [random.uniform](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.uniform) waits for arguments of `int` type.

You could have fixed it by simply:

```
x = random.uniform(-1*(int(squareSize)),int(squareSize))
```

But, better cast `squareSize` to `int` once at the beginning:

```
squareSize = int(raw_input("Enter a square size:"))
```

The code eventually should look like this:

```
import random

squareSize = int(raw_input("Enter a square size:"))

print "#" * (squareSize + 2)
for i in range(0,squareSize):
    print "#", " " * (squareSize) - 2, "#"
print "#" * (squareSize + 2)

x = random.uniform(-1 * squareSize, squareSize)
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the help and sorry for the late reply. Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

the `raw_input` function returns a string (`str`) and not an integer (`int`)

Since squareSize is a string, you cannot perform the `-` operation on it.
Because this was not what you wanted to do. You wanted to perform a substraction (or the function `random` wanted to) on two integer.

So, for that purpose, you can cast (change the type) of your `squareSize` variable, by transforming the string returned by the `raw_input` into an `int`

```
#defines the size of the square
squareSize = raw_input("Enter a square size:")
```